# Use Firefox Windows profile in Firefox Ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot, firefox, mozilla

I am [trying](http://www.jasom.net/how-to-use-same-firefox-profile-in-dual-boot-linux-ubuntu-windows-installation) to use the FireFox Windows Profile in a FireFox Ubuntu Profile in a Dual Boot Ubuntu/Windows installation.

Here is the edited ~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=windows
IsRelative=0
Path=/media/myself/4604CC4A04CC3EA5/Documents and Settings/my self/Application Data/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/l2fh3jo9.default

;http://www.jasom.net/how-to-use-same-firefox-profile-in-dual-boot-linux-ubuntu-windows-installation
```

But this does not work. After I restart the Ubuntu Firefox, it does not use the Windows' "Firefox profile: ad-dons, bookmarks, history"...

What might be wrong here?

P.S. I know about Firefox sync. It is not the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your Windows partition is mounted as /media and that your Windows username is userName, first copy the (randomly named) old profile directory to your Ubuntu account:

```
cp -r /media/Users/userName/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/*.default ~/.mozilla/firefox/win7profile
```

Then quit Firefox and edit the ~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini file, changing StartWithLastProfile=1 to StartWithLastProfile=0 and adding the following to the end:

```
[Profile1]
Name=win7profile
IsRelative=1
Path=win7profile
```

Restart Firefox. It should then allow you to select which profile you want to use.